# Button with image background and text

Tags: css, button

I have a button with an image background applied to it. Inside the button tag there is some text. To center the text I am using padding to position it. However everytime I change the text inside the position is affected and I need to fix the padding again. Is there a way of keeping the text centred regardless of its length?

My code:

```
 <button type="button" class="scroll_button" id="scroll">SIGN UP NOW</button>

.scroll_button{
background: url('../images/button_arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;
padding: 24px 65px 45px 35px;
border: 0;
float: left;
margin-top: -100px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this -

```
padding: 24px 0px; width: 250px; text-align: center;

.scroll_button{
background: red;
padding: 24px 0px; width: 250px; text-align: center;
border: 0;
float: left;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2BU3N/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align: center;` to center the text horizontally within the button. set height and width to make it the size you need, then use `line-height: /*unit*/;` to center it vertically (Where unit is equal to the height of the element.

```
.scroll_button{
background: url('../images/button_arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;
border: 0;
float: left;
margin-top: -100px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;

    /*centering. adjust to taste*/
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/PN8U3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `padding` and replace with:

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: I specified the width and the height, added text-align center and removed padding and that worked thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align:center;` to center horizontally, and `line-height` set to whatever the height of the parent container is to center the text vertically.